# dense_rank ()over ID values - How to rank ID numbers by order instead of value

Tags: sql, hive, window-functions, dense-rank

I have a situation where there are transactions ordered by end times "ts_end_utc" and each transaction has an agent assigned to it. I want to do add a ranking to each agent (they change throughout the transactions) while following the time sequence. Unfortunately when I use dense_rank, it does the ranking based on the value of the agent ID and does not follow the ordering of "ts_end_utc" in order. Any suggestions?

Ideally I would want the "agent_number" which is my ranking column to start with 1 instead of 2 and then switch over to 2 on the 8th row

dense_rank() over(partition by cte_v3.id_ticket_anchor order by agent) agent_number,

| agent_rank | agent | ts_end_utc | id_ticket_anchor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 200 | 16:53:28 | 95300807 |
| 2 | 200 | 17:01:36 | 95300807 |
| 2 | 200 | 17:06:26 | 95300807 |
| 2 | 200 | 18:09:58 | 95300807 |
| 2 | 200 | 18:17:50 | 95300807 |
| 2 | 200 | 18:20:14 | 95300807 |
| 2 | 200 | 18:51:52 | 95300807 |
| 3 | 201 | 18:53:24 | 95300807 |
| 3 | 201 | 19:13:48 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 199 | 19:15:47 | 95300807 |

Desired Result

| agent_rank | agent | ts_end_utc | id_ticket_anchor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 16:53:28 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 17:01:36 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 17:06:26 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 18:09:58 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 18:17:50 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 18:20:14 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 18:51:52 | 95300807 |
| 2 | 201 | 18:53:24 | 95300807 |
| 2 | 201 | 19:13:48 | 95300807 |
| 3 | 199 | 19:15:47 | 95300807 |

Second Scenario - Current Result

| agent_rank | agent | ts_end_utc | id_ticket_anchor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 16:53:28 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 17:01:36 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 17:06:26 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 18:09:58 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 18:17:50 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 18:20:14 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 18:51:52 | 95300807 |
| 2 | 201 | 18:53:24 | 95300807 |
| 2 | 201 | 19:13:48 | 95300807 |
| 3 | 199 | 19:15:47 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 19:16:55 | 95300807 |

Second Scenario - Desired Result

| agent_rank | agent | ts_end_utc | id_ticket_anchor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 16:53:28 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 17:01:36 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 17:06:26 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 18:09:58 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 18:17:50 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 18:20:14 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 18:51:52 | 95300807 |
| 2 | 201 | 18:53:24 | 95300807 |
| 2 | 201 | 19:13:48 | 95300807 |
| 3 | 199 | 19:15:47 | 95300807 |
| 4 | 200 | 19:16:55 | 95300807 |

[image]

Comment: Please share desired output for better understanding of your problem. And id_ticket_anchor column is missing in your data. Please explain. And please add sample data as text instead of image.

Comment: Thanks for sharing input and output in text format. Upvote for that.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur can you please check my question regarding the second scenario above? I thank you for your original answer and any help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are different ts_end_utc for a single agent within a id_ticket_anchor I have first calculated minimum ts_end_utc for each id_ticket_anchor wise agent with `min(ts_end_utc)over(partition by id_ticket_anchor, agent)` window function.

Then use in order by clause of `dense_rank()`. There might be more than one agent with same minimum ts_end_utc, so `agent` is also used in order by clase.

DB-Fiddle:

```
 create table cte_v3(agent int, ts_end_utc time, id_ticket_anchor int);

 insert into  cte_v3 values(200 ,'16:53:28','95300807');
 insert into  cte_v3 values(200 ,'17:01:36','95300807');
 insert into  cte_v3 values(200 ,'17:06:26','95300807');
 insert into  cte_v3 values(200 ,'18:09:58','95300807');
 insert into  cte_v3 values(200 ,'18:17:50','95300807');
 insert into  cte_v3 values(200 ,'18:20:14','95300807');
 insert into  cte_v3 values(200 ,'18:51:52','95300807');
 insert into  cte_v3 values(201 ,'18:53:24','95300807');
 insert into  cte_v3 values(201 ,'19:13:48','95300807');
 insert into  cte_v3 values(199 ,'19:15:47','95300807');
```

Query:

```
 With cte as 
 (
 select agent,ts_end_utc,id_ticket_anchor,
 min(ts_end_utc)over(partition by id_ticket_anchor, agent) min_ts_end_utc
 from cte_v3
 )
 select dense_rank()over(partition by id_ticket_anchor order by min_ts_end_utc,agent)agent_rank,
 agent,ts_end_utc,id_ticket_anchor
 from cte
```

Output:

| agent_rank | agent | ts_end_utc | id_ticket_anchor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 16:53:28.0000000 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 17:01:36.0000000 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 17:06:26.0000000 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 18:09:58.0000000 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 18:17:50.0000000 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 18:20:14.0000000 | 95300807 |
| 1 | 200 | 18:51:52.0000000 | 95300807 |
| 2 | 201 | 18:53:24.0000000 | 95300807 |
| 2 | 201 | 19:13:48.0000000 | 95300807 |
| 3 | 199 | 19:15:47.0000000 | 95300807 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c92b10e99591ea78eeb525886d30b35f)*

Comment: thank you so much, this answers my question for the most part however, I do have another question. When following this method, if a transaction was to have an agent who was previously assigned it will currently give them their old rank. Is there a way to give them a new rank? I will try to add the desired result below

Comment: I will try to add the desired result above in the original question

Answer (score 0):

You may try this -

```
With cte as 
(Select agent, 
min(ts_end_utc) as MinEnd
from tableName
group by agent 
)
Select 
agent, 
dense_rank() over(partition by cte.agent order by MinEnd) agent_number
from cte;
```

Based on your sample output, I'm assuming your ts_end_utc would always be in serial order, and agent would keep on changing after certain intervals.

Comment: that won't work because each timestamp is different so each rank would be 1 in that case

Comment: can you share sample output that you're looking for? that would certainly help

Comment: please see edits above with sample desired output @rajeevpande

Comment: so I need this on every row partitioned by the id_ticket_anchor. I believe this is just 1 query result?

Comment: Yes, this is based on the sample output you shared. I was not sure if that was already partitioned (subset of larger dataset)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233639/discussion-between-rajeev-pande-and-harry-barsegyan).